# How to add a field to an OSM file in Python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, ogr

I am writing a program that takes in a .osm file and then calculates some new attributes for that feature.

I am using the python libraries gdal and ogr to help deal with the data. So far OGR has proven to be a very useful library for parsing and accessing the OSM file.

I was wondering if it possible to add an additional field to the OSM file using OGR.

There is a **.SetField()** function, but it only seems to work on fields that already exist. Is there a way I can design my own field and add it as an extra field to the OSM file?

Bonus points if I can keep the original OSM file intact for testing purposes!

Alternatively, it doesn't have to use OGR, any Python library will do.

Comment: did you see this post:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/how-to-add-attribute-field-to-existing-shapefile-via-python-without-arcgis

Comment: The GDAL OSM driver is read only so adding fields and writing them to .osm file is not possible. I believe that it is possible to join external data by common feature ids.

Comment: Could you provide a tutorial on how to do that? It would be greatly appreciated.